# RecyclerView change UI of other items when an item is clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` in which when a user clicks on an item, the background color of the `RecyclerView` changes. When the user clicks on another item, I want the background color of the previous selected item to return to normal and the new item's background color to change. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Simple way is have a global variable, save position on click of item and `notifyDataSetChanged` and in `onBindView` compare the position if equal then set background color else set it to normal.

Code snippet

```
int clickedPosition;
boolean clicked;

public void onBindView(ViewHolder holder,int position){
    //your code
    if(clicked){
    if(position == clickedPosition)
       holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(...);
    else
       holder.itemView.setBackGroundColor(..your default color..);
    }
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(...){
        clickedPosition = position;
        clicked = true; 
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `onBindView` only called at the creation of the Recycler View?

Comment: it will be called everytime...on notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: and i missed something....wait ..leme modify my answer a bit

Comment: You could call `notifyItemChanged(position)` on both the previous and new selected items to prevent having to redraw the entire list

Comment: yes @Eselfar i agree..one can...